# Jasmine 2 - Testing Angular Factory that calls Service onSuccess case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

In the Factory I have a function:

```
factory.save = function(preference) {
   ... 
   MyService.create(createCmd, onSuccess, onError);
   ...    
}
```

Where, in the same factory:

```
var onSuccess = function(data) {
  console.log("123")
}
var onError = function(data) {
  console.log("123")
}
```

I want to test that

1. factory invokes the `create` method
2. it invokes the `onSuccess` - so then I could extend my test, testing whatever `onSuccess` does

But for now I do not see the message "123" in output while running my test, which looks like this:

```
 it('should call Create() on save', function() {

        // given
        factory = $injector.get('MyFactory');
        service = $injector.get('MyService');
        spyOn(service, 'create').and.callThrough();    // spying on service

        // when
        factory.save("{'some':'some-value'}");

        // then
        expect(service.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

The test is green [image].

**The question is:** How to make `onSuccess` or `onError` to be invoked ? **To print "123"**

In reality it invokes `onSeccess` or `onError` - so the code is working itself.

**UPDATE:**

My Factory code (short version):

```
angular.module('factories').factory('MyFactory', ['MyService',
                            function MyFactory(MyService) {
    'use strict';

    var factory = this;
    factory.userPreferenceId = -1;

    factory.save = function(preference) {
        MyService.create(preference, onSuccess, onError);
    };

    var onSuccess = function(data) {
        console.log("123");
        factory.userPreferenceId = data.preferenceID;
    };
    var onError = function(data) {
        console.log("123");
    };

    return factory;
}]);
```

Service code (if one asks for it):

```
angular.module('services').factory('MyService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/userpreference/:id/:action',
    {id: "@id"}, //parameters default
    {
        create: { method: "POST", params: {action : "create"}},
    });
}]);
```

Comment: can you post your factory as well?

Comment: see UPDATE - the Factory code.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions (while I try to reproduce your issue).

Dont use console.log, use the angular's `$log` service. I would write your factory as:

```
angular.module('factories').factory('MyFactory', ['$log','MyService',
                            function MyFactory($log, MyService) {
    'use strict';

    var factory = this;
    factory.userPreferenceId = -1;

    factory.save = function(preference) {
        MyService.create(preference, onSuccess, onError);
    };

    var onSuccess = function(data) {
        $log.debug("123");
        factory.userPreferenceId = data.preferenceID;
    };
    var onError = function(data) {
        $log.debug("123");
    };

    return factory;
}]);
```

and then in your tests you can inject it like:

```
$log = $injector.get('$log')
```

and test if something is written in the console or what is written. e.g.

```
  it('should log ', ->
    expect($log.debug.logs.length).not.toEqual(0)
  )
```

Also as I can see from your code you are returning `$resource` and `create` is a callback inside `$resource`, so is not public and you cant do `service.create`

Comment: That is all right with $resource. create() is accessible. I works magically. Whether I use $log or console.log onSuccess and onError is not invoking during the test.

Answer (score 0):

What are you testing? It seems to me that you're trying to test the functionality of `MyService` in the tests of `factory`.

I'd recommend testing only for correct invocation of `.create` method with:

```
var pref = 'something',
    a, b...; // your callback functions
factory.save(pref);
expect(service.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(pref, a, b);
```

And test the fact that the functions are actually called in the tests of `MyService`, for example:

```
MyService.create('good', x);
expect(x).toHaveBeenCalled();

MyService.create('bad', _, y);
expect(y).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: I can do this: expect(service.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedCreateCmd, jasmine.any(Function), jasmine.any(Function)); But that is not a question. If I put my functions, 'a' and 'b' (onSuccess, onError) - that will not workout. But the question was why onSucces and onError was not calling - I see no entrance to those functions during the test. Like if it call some fake function but not real one..